# How to bypass Microsoft Defender from my qt installer?

Tags: qt, camera, qt-installer, windows-defender, smartscreen

I have created an installer using the qt Installer in W8.1. When I want to install it in W10, Microsoft Defender is showing me a security message:

[image: Text]

How I can bypass this message?, my software is using just a camera, I didn't have any problem in virustotal.com as well

Answer (score 1):

You should sign your app using signtool

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/cryptography-tools